# Turn off mouse LED lights on linux

Tags: linux, logitech-mouse

I have a Logitech G302, a fine mouse. However, it glows blue, and the intensity increases and decreases. This can be distracting and I would like to turn off the lighting inside the mouse. How can I do this? The software that normally controls it is only available for OSX and Windows.

Comment: Which Linux distro are you using? You could try [Piper](https://github.com/libratbag/piper) mouse configuration utility. There are also a few other posts where people have used xbindkeys, which is for Arch, but other have had success using it on Ubuntu.

Comment: Hey, I'm using Linux Mint. I am trying to install Piper now (thanks for the rec!) but when i use Mason to build it i get the error "meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Compiler cc can not compile programs."

Comment: Do you have gcc installed? Try `gcc -v` or `which gcc` If nothing shows up do `sudo apt-get install gcc` and then `sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev`

Comment: I've got gcc installed already , the issue i guess is that meson is looking in the wrong place for it? Someone in an IRC told me to apt-get install build-essential which works - until meson tells me that "native dependency libudev not found".

Comment: `libudev` can be installed by `sudo apt-get install libudev-dev libsystemd-dev` .... I hate configuring compilers lol.

Comment: Which version/mint flavor are you using?

Comment: Thanks  mate, it got a little further this time... now it tells me libevdev isn't found. lol. i'm gonna keep plugging away at installing everything it tells me i don't have, hopefully it ends soon! :P

i'm on mint 19 xfce

Comment: This is wild, it's telling me I don't have python3 installed...which is definitely not true.

Comment: Did you get my chat notification?

Comment: I did not but i just opened a chat between us, I think.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79967/discussion-between-mc-lunar-and-drzoo).

Comment: Try a hardware mod. If the mouse is easy to open, put a piece of dark paper or tape over the LED.

Comment: On newer versions of Logitech Hub, you need to set it to On-Board Memory Mode for the settings to persist when you change computers. The steps are: 1. Edit the 'active profile' by disabling the lighting settings. 2. Click on the 'settings' icon on the top right. 3. (Optional): Disable 'startup effect'  4. Enable on-board memory. 5. Set the SLOT 1 Profile to the 'Desktop' profile you just edited. This will store the changes on the mouse instead of on the computer you're using.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since most Logitech gaming mice store the mouse profile and settings on the mouse, you can use a Windows or Mac OS to install the Logitech Gaming Software and configure your mouse how you want it. Once you're done, you can unplug the mouse and plug it into the Linux system, and it will still have the same desired behavior.

If you only have access to a Linux OS and you want to change your mouse configuration, you can try to download and install [Piper mouse configuration utility](https://github.com/libratbag/piper).

Comment: I was able to turn off the LEDs of my G703 with Piper on Ubuntu.

Comment: The _G102_ and _G203_ mice can be set using **Onboard Memory Manager** (_Windows_), and the setting then also works on _Linux_.

Comment: Configuring under macOS and plugging in under Linux made my G703 turn on the lights again. Disabling them with Piper worked though.

Comment: *piper* and its *ratbagd* friend were hellish to meson build and install, to finally not work.  I followed your advice and used a Mac to change the mouse config using G Hub, and save "on board". That config remained on Linux, thanks.

Comment: [this one](https://github.com/smasty/g203-led) is pretty good (does not save), and [this one](https://dev.webonomic.nl/using-a-logitech-g203-mouse-under-linux) about piper & ratbagd is made by someone who knows what they talk about.

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't get Piper installed. However, this worked for me, for a G102 Mouse:

```
git clone https://github.com/smasty/g203-led.git
cd g203-led
virtualenv ./env
env/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
sudo ./g203-led.py solid 000000
```

I presume it'll work for the G203, since that's what it's designed for, and presumably it'll work for other G-series mice, including the G302.

Comment: For lightsync mice, you just need to put "lightsync" in the command like this `sudo ./g203-led.py lightsync solid 000000` which is what is stated in the docs [in the git repo](https://github.com/smasty/g203-led).

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/green5/g102-dpi-color

Logitech G102 dpi to mouse color mapper

Comment: Link-only answers are not considered as real answers here: please explain how the page you linked to solves the problem posed in the question.

Comment: Presumably, you are suggesting that, as the G203 code from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1588218/399707) worked on a G102 mouse - and maybe for a G302 mouse - then, this code may also work for both G203 and G302 mice? If so, then please [edit] and explicity add that to your answer, rather than letting readers having to try and deduce that themselves...